# service worker file is not updated on browser when deployed

Tags: service-worker

I have Vanilla Js app that is deployed on github with Heroku (BackEnd). The app was already deployed and I just updated some CSS. And The app is locally updated on Development mode and Production mode both. But on github link, The update is not shown. Service-worker file is not updating. chacheName is the old one (v7), not the updated one (v10) when i check in source /google inpect. I have tired to unregister and update sw and cleared all site date in clear storage/ application / google inspect. But it's still not working. I have no idea what causing this issue. 
Thank you !

service-worker.js

```
const cacheName = 'v10';
const cacheFiles = [
    '/',
    '/resources/css/style.css',
    '/resources/css/queries.css',
    '/resources/js/app.js',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400',
    '/resources/assets/img/background.jpeg',
    '/resources/assets/img/flightnook.jpeg',
    '/resources/assets/img/omnifood.jpeg',
    '/resources/assets/img/weather.jpeg',
    '/resources/assets/img/workflow.jpeg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/icon/nav-close.svg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/icon/nav-open.svg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/icon/svg-symbol.svg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/logo/css3.svg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/logo/nodejs.svg',
    '/resources/assets/svg/logo/svg-logo.svg',
    '/vendors/css/normalize.css',
    '/vendors/js/cache-polyfill.js',
];

if( 'function' === typeof importScripts) {
    importScripts('/vendors/js/serviceworker-cache-polyfill.js');
}

self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Installed');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                console.log('[Service Worker] Caching cacheFiles');
                return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(`[Service Worker] Caching cacheFiles: ${err}`))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Activated');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(thisCacheName => {
                    if (thisCacheName !== cacheName) {
                        console.log(`[Service Worker] Removing Cached Files from Cach-${thisCacheName}`);
                    }
                    return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Fetching ${e.request.url}`);
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(`[Service Worker] Found in cache ${e.request.url}${response}`);
                    return response;
                }

                const requestClone = e.request.clone();
                return fetch(requestClone)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response) {
                            console.log('[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ');
                            return response;
                        }
                        const responseClone = response.clone();
                        caches.open(cacheName)
                            .then(cache => {
                                cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                                console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached', e.request.url);
                                return response;
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err));
            })
    );
});
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle  see "updating the serviceworker" section in the link. it docs your issue and explains details of updates

Comment: Thanks @RobertRowntree. I solved the problem with the reference you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, I have changed two parts.
Changed cacheName value to an array instead of a string and Revised the condition in the map method to check if the existing versions are included in the cacheName array. If it's false, delete them.

```
const cacheName = ['jiah-static-v2'];

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Activated');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(thisCacheName => {
                    if (!cacheName.includes(thisCacheName)) {
                        console.log(`[Service Worker] Removing Cached Files from Cach-${thisCacheName}`);
                        return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});
```